# branding Bigbluebutton looking for BBBDefault.css file

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc, bigbluebutton

I've got bigbluebutton latestcode forked and cloned locally. I'm in process of customization and branding. I found handful template css files under 
~/dev/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-client/src/branding/css directory.

I compiled some of these .css with flex mxmlc and configured under:
/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/config.xml 
all works OK and I can see changed skin on the client, I can start conference sessions etc.

My problem is:

I'm not able to see the icons on the presenter's screen (whiteboard editing icons). I'm sure these files are there under ../../asset directory.

I'm looking for:

1> BBBdefault.css file: this is default css that comes prepackaged with the code. I could not locate this file in gighub cloned software.

2> does anyone have an example of complete .css file ? or could point out solution to my problem?

Regards,
GT

Answer (score 0):

The BigBluebutton use the font-awesome icon library, that means that you just can edit the icons on /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/index.html and if you want to go a little bit further you can add some custom style at /var/www/bigbluebutton-default/css/style.css

All the info about customization can be found here:
https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/customize.html#modify-the-default-landing-page
regads

Answer (score -2):

BBBdefault.css location is

/bigbluebutton-client/branding/default/style/css
under css you can find BBBdefault.css file